# Do not run a category of slow JUnit tests by default in Maven and every IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ, ...) without an explicit TestSuite

Tags: eclipse, junit, intellij-idea, jenkins, maven-3

I have a set of really slow tests, which take a week to run. (They literally run some code non-stop for about a week).

Naturally, no developer (or even the default build job) wants to run these tests. Only a specific, separate build job has the time to run them. So **these tests needs to be disabled by default**.

JUnit's [categories](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Categories) seemed perfect for this: I annotated those slow tests with `@Category(SlowTests.class)`. Problem is that they are still run because:

- I don't want to maintain TestSuite classes because we add Tests on a daily basis. I have 0 TestSuite classes: Maven, IntelliJ and Eclipse just run all the Test classes from my module. Including all those slow tests.
- Even if we had TestSuite classes, most of the open source contributors would still try to run all Test classes from IntelliJ or Eclipse, think it hangs and give up running tests. Those slow tests needs to be excluded by default. Preferably without any extra configuration in IntelliJ or Eclipse.

**How do I exclude a category of slow JUnit tests by default without using an explicit TestSuite?**

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA specific solution would be moving these tests into a separate module so that your main module has no dependency on it, then share tests run configuration for all tests with the classpath setting to the module with your normal tests, this way slow tests will never run unless you create a specific run configuration for this slow tests module classpath.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This **works by default, in Maven, IntelliJ and Eclipse**:

```
import static org.junit.Assume.assumeTrue;

@Test
public void mySlowTest() {
    assumeTrue("true".equals(System.getProperty("runSlowTests")));
    ...
}
```

To run them anyway, simply add VM argument `-DrunSlowTests=true`.

Semantically speaking, it's totally wrong. But it works :)

Comment: You can just put ```@Ignore``` near your ```@Test``` and it will be the same effect but without long stacktrace...

Comment: @dant3 See the question why that doesn't fulfill our requirements. We still want to run these stress tests on the stress job build on the jenkins server. Ignore would always ignore them.

Comment: This would mean that I need to use this assumeTrue statement in each and every test method... is my understanding correct ?

Comment: yes, in every "slow test method". I call them "turtle tests" and activate them with -DrunTurtleTests=true.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know there is no way of preventing Eclipse from running certain tests by default.

Running certain categories from Maven is easy enough using

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludedGroups>${tests.exclude}</excludedGroups>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And then define `tests.exclude` in certain maven profiles.

Maintaining test suites in JUnit is indeed too much work with the current version of JUnit as I've written about in [a blogpost](http://alex.nederlof.com/blog/2012/11/21/separating-the-fast-from-the-slow-junit-tests/). I also explain how [a library called cpsuite](http://www.johanneslink.net/projects/cpsuite.jsp) automatically does the Suite administration for you like this:

```
@RunWith(ClasspathSuite.class) // Loads all unit tests it finds on the classpath
@ExcludeBaseTypeFilter(SlowTest.class) // Excludes tests that inherit SlowTest
public class FastTests {}
```

However, in both methods, Eclipse by default will still just run all Java files with a `@Test` annotation in them.

Comment: Interesting, too bad it doesn't work for Eclipse and IntelliJ by default.

Answer (score 1):

Why not making Integration test out of slow running test. Using the maven-failsafe-plugin which would handle such cases via different naming conventions. For example *IT.java which are Themen long runnin test. Furthermore i would suggest to put the activation into a profilr so everyone can control to run those test or not which should be the default

Comment: Works for maven, but the problem is that Eclipse and IntelliJ will still try to run those tests because they are in src/test/java.

Comment: Usually you run only a few test inside Eclipse/IntelliJ instead of all. So i don't really see a problem.

Comment: Our contributors are used to running all the tests in Eclipse/IntelliJ, before sending in a pull request. Educating them about which tests to include/exclude is time-consuming. In practice, it's hard to get to get them to read even just the README: it should just work correctly by default. But if they can't run the non-slow tests locally easily, they are far more likely to send in a bad pull request and waste a bit of their time and mine.